# Allow non-root user go get network traffic statistics

Tags: networking, stat, sysfs

I know that I can use

```
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes
```

to see the amount of received bytes. Sadly I only can run this command as root.

When I am another user, I get `cat: /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes: Permission denied`

Is there an easy way to allow non-root users to read this file? Currently a non-root is not allowed to access any of the directories in path.

I also tried to use `ifconfig`, but there I get this error

```
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (No such file or directory). Limited output.
```

Comment: once use `ip a` or `ip link` with normal user.

Comment: What distribution are you using, with what kernel version? Are you using a security framework such as SELinux? On Debian stable, this file is world-readable. Which directories are not world-readable on that path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this file is public by default.

Check if there are startup scripts that restrict permissions on your system, either with traditional file permissions or with a security framework such as SELinux or AppArmor.

If you want to leave most directories opaque but allow access to this one file, you can add a sudo rule. To allow all users in `somegroup` to run the command `sudo cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes`, run `visudo` and add a rule like

```
%somegroup ALL = NOPASSWD: cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes
```

Comment: Hey, I tried to copy your example line and exchanged the somegroup by my group and it told me, there is a syntax error. But thanks for the Idea, i finally did it this way, and it worked fine `somegroup ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes
somegroup ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes`